Force refresh screen when navigating back to previous
I'm having a problem on how to refresh my screen when clicking back button from browser. The weird part of this is it's only replicable when deployed on staging servers. In localhost I didn't encounter any of this since it refreshes upon clicking the back button.
Here's my code
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
      if (url === router.asPath) {
        router.replace(router.asPath);
      }
    };
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router]);

Expected output
From Screen 1 -> Navigate to screen 2 -> Click browser back button -> Force refresh screen 1

I've come across a solution that uses window.location.reload() combined with the beforeunload event to force a page reload. Here's the code I'm considering:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
      if (url === router.asPath) {
        window.location.reload(); // Forces the page to reload
      }
    };

    const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
      window.onpopstate = () => {
        window.location.reload();
      };
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, [router]);

  return <div>Your component code</div>;
};

This solution forces the page to reload when the browser back button is clicked.

Thanks but tried your solution, still doesn't work

please share more details and try this:
const MyComponent = () => {
const router = useRouter();
useEffect(() => {
const handlePopState = (event: PopStateEvent) => {
// This forces a reload of the page when the user clicks the back button
if (event.state) {
window.location.reload();
}
};
// detect when the back button is pressed
window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);

return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
};

}, []);
return Your component code;
};
